how to shutdown sockets owned by an other thread
In my application I'm making use of unix domain sockets to perform local communication and I've used the uds crate for that. I need to shutdown the sockets(both listeners and clients, selectively), but with my current code design I'm not able to. Can somebody help me here.
main.rs
mod uds_listener;
mod uds_client;

use std::thread::JoinHandle;

use uds_listener::UdsListener;
use uds_client::UdsClient;
    
fn main() {
    let mut uds_listeners_thread_join_handle_list: Vec<JoinHandle<()>> = Vec::new();
    for i in  0..256 {
        let uds_listnener = UdsListener::new(&format!("{}{}{}", "/tmp/sock_", i.to_string(), ".sock"));
        let uds_listener_jh = uds_listnener.spawn_thread();
        uds_listeners_thread_join_handle_list.push(uds_listener_jh);
    }

    let mut uds_clients_thread_join_handle_list: Vec<JoinHandle<()>> = Vec::new();
    for i in  0..256 {
        let uds_client = UdsClient::new(&format!("{}{}{}", "/tmp/sock_", i.to_string(), ".sock"));
        let uds_client_jh = uds_client.spawn_thread();
        uds_clients_thread_join_handle_list.push(uds_client_jh);
    }

    // but how to request threads blocked on data reception to terminate
    // one way is to shutdown the socket(both read and write, which will result in data reception of length 0), but that's not possible with my current code design as socket is owned by thread
    println!("waiting for listener threads to join");
    while let Some(ljh) = uds_listeners_thread_join_handle_list.pop() {
        let _ = ljh.join();
    }

    println!("waiting for client threads to join");
    while let Some(cjh) = uds_clients_thread_join_handle_list.pop() {
        let _ = cjh.join();
    }
}

uds_listener.rs
use std::thread;

use uds::UnixSeqpacketListener;

pub struct UdsListener {
   listener: UnixSeqpacketListener,
}

impl UdsListener {
   pub fn new(sock_name: &str) -> Self {
      Self {
         listener: Self::bind(sock_name),
      }
   }

   fn bind(sock_name: &str) -> UnixSeqpacketListener {
      match UnixSeqpacketListener::bind(sock_name) {
         Ok(listener) => listener,
         Err(e) => panic!("uds listener bind failed for {sock_name}: {e:?}"),
      }
   }

   pub fn spawn_thread(mut self) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
      thread::spawn(move || {
         self.run();
      })
   }

   fn run(&mut self) {
      if let Ok((socket, _)) = self.listener.accept_unix_addr() {
         let mut buff = [0u8; 8192];
         loop {
            match socket.recv(&mut buff) {
               Ok(length) => {
                  if length == 0 {
                     break;
                  }
               },
               Err(e) => panic!("uds listener read failed: {e:?}"),
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

uds_client.rs
use std::{time, thread};

use uds::UnixSeqpacketConn;

pub struct UdsClient {
   socket: UnixSeqpacketConn,
}

impl UdsClient {
   pub fn new(sock_name: &str) -> Self {
      Self {
         socket: Self::connect(sock_name),
      }
   }

   fn connect(sock_name: &str) -> UnixSeqpacketConn {
      loop {
         match UnixSeqpacketConn::connect(sock_name) {
            Ok(socket) => return socket,
            Err(_) => thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(1)),
         }
      }
   }

   pub fn spawn_thread(mut self) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
      thread::spawn(move || {
         self.run();
      })
   }

   fn run(&mut self) {
      let mut buff = [0u8; 8192];
      loop {
         match self.socket.recv(&mut buff) {
            Ok(length) => {
               if length == 0 {
                  break;
               }
            },
            Err(e) => panic!("uds client read failed: {e:?}"),
         }
      }
   }
}

cargo.toml
[package]
name = "udss"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
uds = "0.4.2"


Do you mean to terminate a thread which is currently blocked on self.socket.recv, or do you mean to terminate a thread which is spinning in the infinite loop? For the second you can add a field is_running: bool into your structs, and modify the loop {} into while is_running {}

@AlexeyS.Larionov thread that is blocked on self.socket.recv, I want to terminate. I thought of calling self.socket.shutdown, which will unblock the thread by returning zero length data, which I can use as a condition to exit from the infinite loop. But with my current design it's not possible, as the socket is owned by thread

Have you tried set_nonblocking?

I thought of setting the socket into non blocking mode, but that is consuming too much CPU compared to blocking mode.

Then I don't think there's any way. Maybe set_read_timeout wouldn't be as expensive?

Or maybe you can refactor so that all the sockets are shared between the main thread and worker threads as Arc<RefCell<UnixSeqpacketConn>>, and passed into UdsClient and UdsListener as such. So that the main thread can acquire a reference to the socket at any moment and call shutdown

I personally feel the way I have designed my code isn't good that meets my requirements. Do you have any better way of designing the above code wherein I should be able to call shutdown method on socket from another thread

This is a typical issue for all blocking IO based operations. A typical solution would be to have a single "coordinator" thread which owns all of the sockets, and has a channel to which you can issue commands. The coordinator spawns more threads for recv from each socket, and joins all of the threads which it spawns before returning (so that the recv threads can all borrow from the socket which is owned by the coordinator). One type of message that you define for the coordinator is to close a particular socket (by name or by some other identifier  you have in your domain).

Here's a simplified example of what I mentioned in the comments, that runs in Rust Playground
Basically the socket is now not owned by the client/listener, but it can be shared between threads by wrapping the socket into Arc<RwLock<>>. In particular, this Arc can be accessed from the main thread, and from it a reference to socket can be acquired, which allows to call shutdown on the socket
use std::thread::JoinHandle;
use std::{time, thread};
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};

struct Socket {
    name: String, 
    running: RwLock<bool>,
}
impl Socket {
    fn connect(socket_name: &str) -> Self {
        println!("Connect {}", socket_name);
        Self{ name: socket_name.to_owned(), running: RwLock::new(true) } 
    }
        
    fn shutdown(&self) { 
        println!("Shutdown {}", self.name);
        *self.running.write().unwrap() = false;
    }
    fn recv(&self, buffer: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize, std::io::Error> { 
        let mut x = 0;
        for i in 0..100000 { x += (i % 2) as usize; } 
        let length = if *self.running.read().unwrap() { 100 } else { 0 };
        Ok(length)
    }
}
    
fn main() {
    let mut uds_listeners_list: Vec<(JoinHandle<()>, Arc<RwLock<Socket>>)> = Vec::new();
    for i in  0..4 {
        let uds_listnener = UdsListener::new(&format!("{}{}{}", "/tmp/sock_", i.to_string(), ".sock"));
        let socket = uds_listnener.socket();
        uds_listeners_list.push((uds_listnener.spawn_thread(), socket));
    }

    let mut uds_clients_list: Vec<(JoinHandle<()>, Arc<RwLock<Socket>>)> = Vec::new();
    for i in  0..4 {
        let uds_client = UdsClient::new(&format!("{}{}{}", "/tmp/sock_", i.to_string(), ".sock"));
        let socket = uds_client.socket();
        uds_clients_list.push((uds_client.spawn_thread(), socket));
    }

    // but how to request threads blocked on data reception to terminate
    // one way is to shutdown the socket(both read and write, which will result in data reception of length 0), but that's not possible with my current code design as socket is owned by thread
    println!("waiting for listener threads to join");
    while let Some((ljh, socket)) = uds_listeners_list.pop() {
        socket.read().unwrap().shutdown();
        let _ = ljh.join();
    }

    println!("waiting for client threads to join");
    while let Some((cjh, socket)) = uds_clients_list.pop() {
        socket.read().unwrap().shutdown();
        let _ = cjh.join();
    }
}


pub struct UdsListener {
   socket: Arc<RwLock<Socket>>,
}

impl UdsListener {
   pub fn new(sock_name: &str) -> Self {
      Self {
         socket: Arc::new(RwLock::new(Socket::connect(sock_name))),
      }
   }
   
   pub fn socket(&self) -> Arc<RwLock<Socket>> {
       self.socket.clone()
   }

   pub fn spawn_thread(mut self) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
      thread::spawn(move || {
         self.run();
      })
   }

    fn run(&mut self) {
        let mut buff = [0u8; 8192];
        loop {
            match self.socket.read().unwrap().recv(&mut buff) {
               Ok(length) => {
                  if length == 0 {
                     break;
                  }
               },
               Err(e) => panic!("uds listener read failed: {e:?}"),
            }
        }
    }
}

pub struct UdsClient {
   socket: Arc<RwLock<Socket>>,
}

impl UdsClient {
   pub fn new(sock_name: &str) -> Self {
      Self {
         socket: Arc::new(RwLock::new(Socket::connect(sock_name))),
      }
   }
   
   pub fn socket(&self) -> Arc<RwLock<Socket>> {
       self.socket.clone()
   }
   
   pub fn spawn_thread(mut self) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
      thread::spawn(move || {
         self.run();
      })
   }

   fn run(&mut self) {
      let mut buff = [0u8; 8192];
      loop {
         match self.socket.read().unwrap().recv(&mut buff) {
            Ok(length) => {
            println!("Recv {}", length);
               if length == 0 {
                  break;
               }
               
            },
            Err(e) => panic!("uds client read failed: {e:?}"),
         }
      }
   }
}

Output
Connect /tmp/sock_0.sock
Connect /tmp/sock_1.sock
Connect /tmp/sock_2.sock
Connect /tmp/sock_3.sock
Connect /tmp/sock_0.sock
Connect /tmp/sock_1.sock
Connect /tmp/sock_2.sock
Connect /tmp/sock_3.sock
waiting for listener threads to join
Shutdown /tmp/sock_3.sock
Recv 100
Recv 100
Recv 100
Recv 100
Shutdown /tmp/sock_2.sock
Recv 100
Recv 100
Recv 100
Recv 100
Recv 100
Recv 100
Shutdown /tmp/sock_1.sock
Recv 100
Recv 100
Shutdown /tmp/sock_0.sock
Recv 100
Recv 100
Recv 100
Recv 100
Recv 100
waiting for client threads to join
Shutdown /tmp/sock_3.sock
Recv 100
Recv 100
Recv 100
Recv 0
Shutdown /tmp/sock_2.sock
Recv 100
Recv 100
Recv 0
Shutdown /tmp/sock_1.sock
Recv 0
Shutdown /tmp/sock_0.sock
Recv 0


RwLock<bool> should just be an AtomicBool no?

@kmdreko yeah, but it's just a mock struct, so doesn't matter in this case
